# Sapui5 navTo not working in ajax statement

Tags: ajax, sapui5

I have a form in my page. When a user clicks a button if have no problem this code must navigate my `Tile` page. I am taking this problem:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navTo' of undefined`.

This my code:

```
 onPressGonder: function (evt) {
  var sURL = "xxxxxx";
  $.ajax({  
    url: sURL,  
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.ResultCode === 7) {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error:" +data.Alerts[0].Message+"") ; 
      } else {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Login succesfull.");
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).navTo("Tile");
      }   
    }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a scope problem. The function provided as a success callback is a anonymous function called later on by [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Therefore it is NOT a method of your controller and thereby does not know `this`. By default (as in your anonymous function) `this` refers to the `window` object. So what your basically doing is:

```
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(window).navTo("Tile");
```

And the `window` object obviously does not have a router or a navTo method ;)
The easiest workaround is to make `this` available via the [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) scope as follows:

```
onPressGonder: function (evt) {
  var sURL = "xxxxxx",
      that = this;
  $.ajax({  
    url: sURL,  
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.ResultCode === 7) {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error:" +data.Alerts[0].Message+"") ; 
      } else {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Login succesfull.");
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(that).navTo("Tile");
      }   
    }
  }); 
}
```

Another probably more elegant solution is to use the `context` property of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). It will ensure that any ajax callback will be executed with the provided context (meaning whatever you pass as a context will be referred to as `this` inside your callbacks):

```
  $.ajax({  
    ...
    success: function(data) {
      ...
      sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).navTo("Tile"); 
    },
    context: this
  });
```